# 3 level nested repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, nested-repeater

have a 3 level nested repeater which display menu header and menu items for each group  as shown

in second repeater have 4 check boxes to check some check boxes in third repater with javascript function as shown

```
     <asp:Repeater ID="RpGroups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RpGroups_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="GID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("groupid")%>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                    <div class="panel  panel-primary ">

                        <div class="panel-heading">

                            <h3 onclick="swap(<%# Eval("groupid")%>)" class="panel-title"><%# Eval("groupName")%> <span class="navbar-right glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></h3>


 </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading">



                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body " id="<%# Eval("groupid")%>" hidden="hidden">
                            <div>

                                <asp:Repeater ID="RpMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="FillMenuItems">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">

                                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center"><%# Eval("HeadItemText")%>
                                                    <div class="navbar-right"></div>
                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                                </table>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="RbItems" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive  ">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="alert-danger table-responsive">

                                                                <th class="col-sm-2 ">Page Name</th>
                                                                <th>

                                                                    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Full Add" runat="server" onclick="checkadd(this, 'Add')" />Full Add</th>

                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="Full View" onclick="checkadd(this), 'View'" />Full View</th>

                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="Full Update" onclick="checkadd(this), 'Edit'" />Full Updte</th>

                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" value="Full Delete" onclick="checkadd(this, 'Delete')" />Full Delete</th>

                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%--<div class="table-responsive">
                                                   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">--%>


                                                <tr class="view" >

                                                    <asp:Label ID="PID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tblMenuItemID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                    <td class="col-sm-2"><strong>
                                                        <div><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></div>
                                                    </strong></td>


                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Update" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" /></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <%-- </table>
                                                </div>--%>
                                                <%-- <li>
                                                    <a href="<%# Eval("MenuItemLink")%>"><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></a>
                                                </li>--%>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="GID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("groupid")%>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                    <div class="panel  panel-Lightblue ">

                        <div class="panel-heading">

                            <h3 onclick="swap(<%# Eval("groupid")%>)" class="panel-title"><%# Eval("groupName")%> <span class="navbar-right glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></h3>


 </a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="panel-body " id="<%# Eval("groupid")%>" hidden="hidden">
                            <div>

                                <asp:Repeater ID="RpMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="FillMenuItems">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="panel panel-Lightblue">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">

                                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center"><%# Eval("HeadItemText")%>
                                                    <div class="navbar-right"></div>
                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                                </table>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="RbItems" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive  ">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="alert-danger table-responsive">

                                                                <th class="col-sm-2 ">Page Name</th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Full Add" runat="server" onclick="checkadd(this, 'Add')" />Full Add</th>

                                                                </script>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="Full View" onclick="checkadd(this, 'View')" />Full View</th>

                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="Full Updte" onclick="checkadd(this, 'Edit')" />Full Updte</th>

                                                                <th>
                                                                    <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" value="Full Delete" onclick="checkadd(this, 'Delete')" />Full Delete</th>

                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>



                                                <tr class="view">

                                                    <asp:Label ID="PID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tblMenuItemID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                    <td class="col-sm-2"><strong>
                                                        <div><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></div>
                                                    </strong></td>


                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Update" /></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" /></td>
                                                </tr>


                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

       <script type="text/javascript">
                    function checkadd(chk, name) {
                        if (chk.checked == true) {
                            document.getElementById('<% = RpGroups.ClientID %>');

                            var chk = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
                            var len = chk.length;

                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                if (chk[i].type === 'checkbox' && chk[i].name===name) {
                                    chk[i].checked = elem.checked;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var div = document.getElementById('<% = RpGroups.ClientID %>');

                            var chk = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
                            var len = chk.length;

                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                if (chk[i].type === 'checkbox' && chk[i].name === name) {
                                    chk[i].checked = false;
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                </script>
```

i need `checkbox` with value  (full Add) check all check boxes in `rpitems` with name Add what wrong in my code

[image]

Comment: plz format your code correctly and revert with your intent restated clearly...

Comment: i did some formatting i hope you can understand my goal and please check the screen shot to help you understanding @deostroll

Comment: It's unclear what you want?

Comment: Check Full Add checkbox to check all checkboxes with name Add only in same repeater !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view source and study the rendered markup, you notice that the checkboxes get created with a particular pattern. You can use that fact for your requirement.

Now for the javascript side of things...you need to walk up the DOM tree and find the closes table corresponding to the checkbox clicked.

You are doing something like this:

```
onclick="checkadd(this, 'View')
```

So the first argument to that function is a reference to the checkbox that the user has clicked...Hence we've to find the closest table. Therefore we do something like this...

```
var tbl = findClosestTable(chk); //stores reference to the table that houses checkbox
```

`findClosestTable` is implemented like this:

```
function findClosestTable(el) {
    while(!el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table' && el !== document.body)
        el = el.parentNode;
    if(el == document.body)
        return null;
    else
        return el; //should be the table reference.
}
```

Once you have that, you can get all the input elements by tagname using that reference.

```
var inputElements = tbl.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Now the task is fairly simple.

```
for(var i = 0, j = inputElements.length; i < j; i++ ) {
    var el = inputElements[i];
    if(el.type === 'checkbox' && el.id.indexOf('Add') > 0 && el !== chk) {
        //el is now a reference to your desired checkbox element...
    }
}
```